# Spring security with multiple endpoints

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using http basic authentication for my web application. It has multiple enpoints. My requirement is authenticate user once, and access these different endpoints. Below is the current Spring security configuration.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.security" />

<sec:http use-expressions="true">

    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('Admin','Data Operator','Data Collector')" />
    <sec:http-basic />

</sec:http>

<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="myAuthenticationProvider">
        <sec:password-encoder ref="encoder" />
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>

<bean id="myAuthenticationProvider"
    class="com.test.security.MyUserDetailsService" />


<bean id="encoder"
     class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder">
</bean>
```

Below is the implementation of authenticate provider

```
 package com.test.security;

    import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.test.business.objects.Adminrole;
import com.test.business.objects.Adminuser;
import com.test.business.repository.AdminroleRepository;
import com.test.repository.AdminuserRepository;

@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{

    @Autowired
    private AdminuserRepository adminuserRepository;

    @Autowired
    private AdminroleRepository adminroleRepository;






    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException{



        //find admin user by user name
        List<Adminuser> adminUsers = adminuserRepository.findByUsername(username);
        Adminuser adminUser = adminUsers.get(0);

        //find admin roles by user
        List<Adminrole> adminRoles = adminroleRepository.getAdminRolesByUserId(adminUser.getUserid());

        //create user details object
        MyUserDetails userdetails = new MyUserDetails(adminUser, adminRoles);
        return userdetails;

    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you using http-basic, its not secure. Also, don't use MD5 password encoder, not secure, use BCrypt. Also, your intercept-url says that all pages starting from / should have a logged in user. If that's the case then how will the user arrive on login page because the login page will be a part of /**. Got it?

Comment: What do you mean "endpoints"?